# simplehtmldom how can i extract between two elements

Tags: php, parsing, simple-html-dom

I'm using Simple HTML DOM parser to do this. Basically, I'm trying to extract all `<p>` tags between `<table class="first">` and `<div class="second">`:

```
<div id="main>
   <table class="first">
   <p>
   <p>
   <p>
   <div class="second">
   <p>
</div>
```

In this case, there are 3 `<p>`s, but sometimes it might just be two or even one. Any `<p>` can have id or class. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm unsure. Are the tags messed up there? Are you meant to end the div after the three p's? You could possibly get all the childnodes, then search for div's and tables then loop through those and use them how you would like.

Comment: Depending on how you fix the html, the `p`'s are either siblings of `table` or its descendents. It makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this cannot be done directly with simple-html-dom...

A workarround would be to start at the starting node (ie `table.first`) and get all the following siblings (or nodes of type X [it's up to you to specify which if needed]) untill the end node (ie `div.second`)

Here's a working code: (I modified the input to get a valid html code)

```
$input =  <<<_DATA_
    <div id="main">
        <p>p1</p>

        <table class="first">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>pInTable</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <p>p2</p>
        <p>p3</p>
        <p>p4</p>

        <div class="second">MyDiv</div>

        <p>p5</p>
    </div>
_DATA_;

// Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$html->load($input);

// Get the starting node
$startPoint = $html->find('table.first', 0);

// While the current node has a sibling
while ( $next = $startPoint->next_sibling() ) {
    // And as long as it's different from the end node => div.second
    if ( $next->tag == 'div' && $next->class == 'second' )
        break;
    else{
        // Print the content
        echo $next->plaintext;
        echo '<br/>';
        // And move to the next node
        $startPoint = $next;
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
p2
p3
p4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a lot of good examples in the [manuals page at the section 'descendant'](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

```
//to parse a webpage
$html = file_get_html("your website");

//only for the table
$tablePs = $html->find('table[class="first"] p'); 

//only for the container div
$divPsContainer = $html->find('div[id="main"] p'); 

$divPsSecond = $html->find('div[class="second"] p'); 

//for all in the div
//then you iterate

foreach($tablePs as $p){
..
}

foreach($divPsSecond as $p){
...
}

foreach($divPsContainer as $p){
...
}
?>
```

Comment: The OP wants `<p>` tags in **between** `<table class="first">` and `<div class="second">`.